# Can a Cefsharp popup window call parent window javascript code

Tags: javascript, popup, parent-child, cefsharp

Under CefSharp v57, is there a way to call some javascript code of the parent window (ChromiumWebBrowser) from the popup "child" window?

Under the popup window, I'm trying to reach the *window.opener* property. If I'm calling:

```
window.opener.location.toString();
```

I get this message: 
*Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.*

Of course, my goal is to share some JS code and context of the parent window under the popup. Maybe something else should be called while creating the popup window while using the ILifeSpanHandler implementation?